# Trouble in retrieving the JPEG image from inputstream socket in Android

Tags: android, arrays, inputstream

I want to retrieve the JPEG image from a inputstream socket in Android. Can I actually use Bitmap method and straight away convert input stream to JPG or should I convert the inputstream to byte array and then convert it to a JPG?

The code that I'm actually trying is:

```
            private final BluetoothSocket mmBTSocket;
    private final InputStream mmBTInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmBTOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(BTTAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        mmBTSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(BTTAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        mmBTInStream = tmpIn;
        mmBTOutStream = tmpOut;
    }
                      public void run() {

                      Log.i(BTTAG, "BEGIN mBTConnectedThread");

                        byte[] inBTBuffer = new byte[1024];

                         boolean BTFileEndOne = false;

                         byte[] mBTimageBuffer = new byte[15360]; // 15KB reserved

                               int bytes;

                                bytes = mmBTInStream.read(inBTBuffer);

                for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++) {
                    mBTimageBuffer[mBTfileIndex] = inBTBuffer[i];
                    mBTfileIndex++;
                    // start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    // Log.i(BTTAG, bytes+"="+String.format("%02X",
                    // inBTBuffer[i]));
                    if (i > 0) {
                        if (inBTBuffer[i] == (byte) 0xD9) {
                             BTFileEndOne = true;
                             Log.i(BTTAG, "BTFileEndOne = true");

                            if (inBTBuffer[i - 1] == (byte) 0xFF) {
                                //if (SaveImagetoSD() == true) {

                                    //byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mmBTInStream);   
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, mmBTOutStream);

        String writeTo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "motoduino.jpg")  .toString();                   
         FileOutputStream output = null;  
         try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(writeTo);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`
```

Comment: Looks like from the code what mmBTinStream, is used to send more then one file, so unfortunately BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mmBTinStream) won't work as it needs to see a jpg or png file as it would have been as a file. You will need to save the bytes to file first this way you can also test what it hasn't been corrupted.

Comment: Do you need to use the transferred picture in your app, or are you only saving it and not using it within your app?

Comment: Actually i will be uploading the transferred image to server. But actually im sending only one file from arduino

Comment: First i need to save the received bytes as .JPG in SDcard and then i will upload the image from the SD card.

Comment: I can save the image in SD card actually but i couldnt view the image. It says the image is broken??

Comment: PLease help me bro. I can save the recieved bytes in SD card under the name of moto.JPG but im unable to view it.

Comment: ok you don't need any bitmap code as it doesn't really mater if its a picture or not, you are receiving a file and need to save the bytes to sdcard as the same filetype as its sent, then try open it (once that works, different code for upload to server) files can easily get corrupt and need to make sure it doesn't pick up any extra headers, the best method is opening the original and transferred pictures in notepad and seeing if the beginning and end of the jibberish is the same. Have you got the end of the for loop I cannot see where inBTBuffer gets its next byte.

Comment: Well i checked  both the jibberish thing and they are the same. But i dont know why Decoder is giving a NULL??

Comment: Bro the image bytes look the same before and after transmitting. But i couldnt view the image when it is received and store in the SD. Please help me bro to view the image. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

BitmapFactory can load both png and jpg.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputstream);
```

you can save as jpeg or png with:

```
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outputstream);
```

edit: save to external storage:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if(sdcard!=null){
        File myjpg = new File(sdcard,"test.jpg");
        try{
            OutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(myjpg);
            mybitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, outputstream);
            outputstream.close();
        }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    }else{
        Log.e("jpg save","sdcard not inserted or not ready");
    }
```

you need uses-permission android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks alot for the comment. And how can i save that to SD card?

Comment: When i try in that way it is returning NULL. 11-17 15:46:03.757: D/skia(21948): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Comment: if it is returning null then we need to see how your inputstream is being created.

Comment: To save to external storage you need:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission> in your manifest.

You need your sdcard path: File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
Make sure sdcard!=null
Create a new file from the sdcard path File outfile = new File(sdcard,"myfilename.jpg");
Create the outputstream from that file: OutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
and pass that to the bitmap.compress line in my original answer.

Comment: I have attached the code that im trying to decode. Please have a look at that too bro.